# Are eigenvectors a basis set for any invariant subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (i.e., a real square matrix).
Assume that $v_1,\dots, v_m$ ($m\le n$) are eigenvectors of $A$.

Can any $d-$dimensional invariant subspace of $A$ be constructed using $d$ numbers of $v_i$'s?

Comment: What do you mean by "constructed"?

Comment: No, even assuming that the vectors are linearly independent and exhaust the eigenspaces. Consider a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the $z$-axis, e.g. $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & -1&  0\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$. The only eigenvectors are multiples of $(0,0,1)$, but $W=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is invariant.

Comment: The point is precisely that invariant subspaces are more general than spaces generated by eigenvectors...

Comment: @BigbearZzz, by 'constructing' I mean linear combination.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, what about symmetric matrices?

Comment: @BashirSadeghi: Symmetric matrices are (orthogonally) diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$, and in particular, if $W$ is any invariant subspace of $V$, then the restriction of the action of the matrix to $W$ will also be diagonalizable; thus, $W$ will be spanned by eigenvectors.

Comment: However, even in the case of a diagonalizable matrix, the result is not *quite* right. For example, if you take the identity matrix and you take your $v_i$ to be the standard basis, then any subspace is invariant, but the only subspaces you can generate with subsets of your $v_i$ are the coordinate subspaces. E.g., with $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1=(1,0)$, and $v_2=(0,1)$, you can’t get the subspace $\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ which is invariant under the identity map.